# What is the closed for of a minimization problem?

Tags: optimization, minimization

I have this exercise to do.
[image]

Does someone have hints or solutions?
What is a closed form solution?
Thanks everybody.

Comment: check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAYTs7Rfse8

Comment: [Wiki: Closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression). Example: the similar but more general [linear-regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) has a closed-form solution while the same problem with some side-constraint `x >=0`, [Non-negative least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares) has not and iterative approaches will be needed.